# GetSheet with filtered rows by column value

Tags: javascript, node.js, smartsheet-api

Is there any way of getting the rows that match a value in a determined column?

For instance, I have this table:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
a    | 1    | z
b    | 2    | w
```

I would like to call getSheet() method with some parameter like:

```
filters: [{
    columnId: 12412451251441234, //id for Col1
    type: "CUSTOM",
    criteria: {
        operator: "EQUAL",
        value1: "b"
    }
}]
```

It sould only return the second row...
Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can certainly see the usefulness of the scenario you've described, the [Get Sheet](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet) operation in the Smartsheet API does not currently support querying a sheet for rows where a specific cell contains the specified value. So, you'll need to execute a **Get Sheet** operation (which returns all rows in the Sheet), and then implement your own code to parse the response according to your desired criteria.